Use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to create a file with environment markers?
There are Environment Markers or Requirement Specifiers we can use in requirements.txt. For example, argparse;python_version<"2.7" will tell pip to install argparse only when the python version is less than 2.7.
However, is it possible to generate these environment markers when using pip freeze > requirements.txt? Documentation of pip freeze does not mention a way. I tried the -r option but had no luck. Do we have to edit the requirements.txt file manually after pip freeze?

pip freeze isn't intended to replace a human-maintained list of dependencies. It's a mechanism to describe what was present in a specific actual realized installation, not a replacement for a curated description from which such an environment can be built. If you want a tool with more comprehensive lockfiles, might I suggest switching to poetry?

Does How to maintain pip install options in requirements file made by pip freeze? answer your question?

@KarlKnechtel None of the answers in the linked question shows how to preserve environment markers with pip freeze.

pip cannot do that; pip freeze just lists all currently installed packages. All packages that you've installed directly and all their recursive dependencies. As pip doesn't know which packages are important it doesn't filter the list. As pip doesn't know which environment markers are important it doesn't add any and most probably never will.
The current best practice in this area is: you maintain a list of direct, top-level requirements. You maintain it manually, no tools can help. And you regularly freeze the list of all installed packages into a different file.
There're two schools on how to name these files. One school teaches you maintain requirements.in manually and freeze to requirements.txt. The other says you manually maintain requirements.txt and freeze to requirements.lock.
In addition to pip freeze there're many tools that can help you to freeze the list of packages in different formats and restore (i.e. reinstall) them into a new empty virtual environment. I recommend you to take a look at poetry and pip-tools.
Personal note: for big projects I maintain manually 2 (two) list of requirements: development and production. To avoid duplication development file includes production file using -r requirements.txt. See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/

Thank you. Do you personally use tools like poetry and pip-tools? Or do you prefer maintaining the files manually?

@Betty poetry and other tools don't replace manual maintenance. You always maintain source list(s) of requirements with environment markers manually. All tools help to construct frozen lists of requirements and later reinstall them — exactly the same versions.
